# Can't open storyboard files from document tree for specific project

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

In Xcode, I can't open `.storyboard` files from the document navigator for the specific project I'm working on.  If I open a different project I can open them fine, and when I go to finder and manually open the file it loads the interface builder and I can edit the file perfectly fine.  I noticed that in the document navigator the icon is grayed out.
[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnohp.png)

It is very subtle in the screenshot, but the opacity is less than 100%.

I've tried cleaning and restarting, and I've even reinstalled Xcode without any luck.

Comment: Have you tried copying them and re-adding them to your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per I'L'I's comment, removing the files, and then dragging them back into the editor fixed the bug.